# Reading csv file names from a list and using them in a script

Tags: python, csv, ipython, filenames

I have a folder with csv files where each file has a string at the start identifying the game and a tag at the end identifying which table from that games.  Example:

```
20020905_nyg_scoring.csv
20020905_nyg_team_stats.csv
20020908_buf_scoring.csv
20020908_buf_team_stats.csv
```

I've written a script that pairs csv files by the first part of the file name into a dictionary and then turns that dictionary into a list.  I want to read the file name pairs in and perform dataframe shaping on each pair together.  Ultimately, I will concat the data from the paired files into a single dataframe (concat is not my issue here).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

game_list = {}
path = r'C:\Users\jobon\Documents\New NFL Stats\Experimental\2002 Game Logs'
for file in os.listdir(path):
    game_pairing = game_list.get(file[:12],[])
    game_pairing.append(file)
    game_list[file[:12]] = game_pairing

game_pairs = []
for game, stats in game_list.items():
    game_pairs.append(stats)

for scoring, team_stats in game_pairs:
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        df1 = pd.read_csv(scoring, header = 0, index_col = 0)
        df1.drop(['Detail', 'Quarter', 'Time', 'Tm'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
        ...more shaping...
```

I expect to end with a final set of data frames generated from each pair of game files that I can concat.

Instead I get

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-fb1d4aa9f003> in <module>
     18 for scoring, team_stats in game_pairs:
     19     for file in os.listdir(path):
---> 20         df1 = pd.read_csv(scoring, header = 0, index_col = 0)
     21         #df1.drop(['Detail', 'Quarter', 'Time', 'Tm'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
     22         print(df1)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'20020905_nyg_scoring.csv' does not exist: b'20020905_nyg_scoring.csv'
```

The files are in the folder, and it worked for building the list, but I don't know why it suddenly can't find the files now.

Comment: Attempted:
`df1 = pd.read_csv(scoring.decode("utf-8"), header = 0, index_col = 0)`
and got:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

So I tried:
`df1 = pd.read_csv(codecs.decode(scoring, encoding='ASCII', errors='strict'), header = 0, index_col = 0)`
and got:
TypeError: decoding with 'utf-8' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code. I think the problem is that your `.csv` files are in the folder `path`, so you cannot find the files if just use the filename `scoring` without the directory name `path`. To fix this, you need

```
scoring = os.path.join(path, scoring)
```

in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the the first variable that you are passing in the read_csv method is not a string literal but a byte literal. That is why the error mentions a file b'20020905_nyg_scoring.csv' and not '20020905_nyg_scoring.csv'. That b in the beginning denotes a byte literal.

Changing

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(scoring, header = 0, index_col = 0)
```

to

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(scoring.decode("utf-8"), header = 0, index_col = 0)
```

should fix your issue

Comment: Tried and got:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'